# How to get attribute of hidden element

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to use python and selenium to get the value of an element, however, because the element type is "hidden", I get NoSuchElementException. How should I find the hidden element?

below is the html source

```
<span id="twisterNonJsData">
<input type="hidden" name="ASIN" value="B07DGSKM7D">
</span>
```

below is my code

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_id('twisterNonJsData')
asin=elem.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@name="ASIN"]')
print(asin.get_atrribute('value'))
```

Comment: What website is it? Also is it in any iframes?

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` means that either your locator is incorrect, the element might be in an IFRAME, or you may need to add a wait for the element to be present. If the element was actually there and the locator is good, Selenium will find it whether it's hidden or not. Now... Selenium WILL throw an exception if you try to click or otherwise interact with a hidden element but it's `ElementNotInteractable` (or something like that), not `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: it turns out to be not because of the type being hidden, but because of the JS rendering removed this part from the html source. Using selenium doesn't find it, but using request could find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be easily achieved with BeautifulSoup.

You grab the page source via an HTTP requests. In my example I use the requests library. Then you can load the HTML inside BeautifulSoup to find your element.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

req = get('http://example.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(req.content), 'html.parser')

elem = soup.find('input', {'name': 'ASIN'})
```

Don't forget to install the required libraries with pip.

```py
pip3 install requests
pip3 install bs4
```

Comment: I have to use selenium not request for this site

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using JS Executor to get the hidden value. It would look something like this:

```
result = driver.execute_script(return document.getElementByName("ASIN").value")
```

Comment: result = self.driver.execute_script(return document.getElementByName('ASIN').value")
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax